# I can't hear my boyfriends speakers when he's sharing his screen to show a video

Tags: audio, skype, speakers

So ever since the new update Skype has been pretty bad. My boyfriend likes to share his screen with me so we can watch the video together, but now because of the update I can't hear the sound from his speakers (and no he's not wearing earphones).

I can hear him talk, but I can't hear the sound coming from his speakers. What's the deal with that? Nothing in the audio setting were changed.

Comment: Has he enabled noise cancellation for his microphone or in Skype?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Since the update is problematic for you, why not revert back to the previous version/

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for a way to do this in Windows, and I found this great video explaining how to set it up: [Skype Voice Chat with Game Audio & NO ECHO!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SDBoGX1oACI)

It uses a program called VoiceMeeter. You will need to download these two parts of it:

1. [VoiceMeeter](https://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/)
2. [Virtual Audio Cable](https://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/index.htm)

In summary,

- You can hear them (no echo)
- They can hear you (no echo)
- You can enable them to hear your desktop sounds

All of these parts can be enabled/disabled at will, and you can mute and adjust the volume of each part individually, as well as overall.

> The reason it works is because Skype/Discord allow you to choose a microphone input AND sound output. If the sound output is excluded from your system sound, it won't be sent back to the people you're chatting with, but this program still allows you to listen to it by routing it to your headphones with a "virtual cable."

Skype will, of course, be used for the video and/or screen sharing.